# Log streaming and premissions with .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to stream a log file my application writes. I used https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/logs-streamtocloudwatch-linux.config as a starting point. Unfortunately it seems that `/etc/awslogs` is no longer the correct path to add additional CloudWatch config.

I found out that I can place the file in `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/my.json` to make it work. But I'm unable to create this file and make CloudWatch parse it using `.ebextensions`. I tried to do this using a file with the following contents. The file does not exist after deployment. If I used the filename proposed by awsdocs the file was created.

`.ebextensions/02-logs-streamtocloudwatch.config`:

```
files:
  "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/my.json" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        {
            "logs": {
                "logs_collected": {
                    "files": {
                        "collect_list": [
                            {
                                "file_path": "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/my.log",
                                "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-env/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/my.log",
                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, my log file should have `666` permissions for now (I know that that's not the idea). Creating a file in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_permissions.sh` containing the following content using `.ebextensions` does not seem to work either.

`.ebextensions/04-permissions.config`:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_dbg_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chmod 666 /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/dbg.log
```

What am I missing about how to use .ebextensions and/or the CloudWatch config in Beanstalk?

I would like to not only fix this, but understand the problem (where can I create/modify files when/how). I appreciate  any help...

Comment: ". But I'm unable to create this file and make CloudWatch parse it using .ebextensions." why? How did you try doing that? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin: I added the files I used to my post. A big part of my problem is that I don't get why I seem to be able to create files and change permissions in some locations, but not everwhere. I'm guessing that I run into some kind of timing problem (using the wrong hook), maybe..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/` does not exist, as you correctly noted. The reason is that you are probably using **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) based EB environment, instead of AL1. The folder was only available in the old EBs based on AL1.

On AL2, there is **new hooks mechanism** as described in [Application deployment platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you have to adapt your code to use the new hooks, or switch back to EB environment based on AL1.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Marcin's answer I was able to add my log file to the log streaming config:

`.platform/hooks/postdeploy/02-logs-streamtocloudwatch.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '{
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/my.log",
                        "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-env/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/my.log",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}' > "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/my.json"
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a append-config
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a stop
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a start
```